# PHP $var undefined when using multiple require()

Tags: php, undefined, require

I'm setting a $baseurl in a settings.php file.

In my index.php, I've got 3 require() in a row for the settings.php/header.php/masthead.php.

When I come to echo out the $baseurl it's undefined. If I define the $baseurl within the header.php then it works within the header.php file.

How can I get the $baseurl to be defined within the settings.php file and usable within each require() ?

Comment: To clarify: You are requiring settings.php, then header.php, and then masthead.php.  $baseurl is defined inside settings.php but is undefined inside header.php?  Inside header.php, what is happening on the line that throws the undefined variable error?  Is it inside a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Order of inclusion

The file that sets `$baseurl` must be `require_once()` first for the subsequent files to have access to the variable.

### Function Scope

If you are defining `$baseurl` in a function or the files are `require_once()` from within a function then `$baseurl` will be trapped in that functions scope. This would the case if `settings.php` looked something like:

```
<?php
function setup_config() {
    $baseurl = 'http://www.example.org';
}
```

Or requiring from within a function

```
<?php
function include_a_file($file) {
    require_once 'my/base/path/' . $file;
}
```

This is documented in the [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) portion of the PHP Manual.

One way to work around this is to add `$baseurl` as an element in [`$GLOBALS` array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) instead of as a standalone variable:

```
$GLOBALS['config']['baseurl'] = 'my/base/url/';
```

**Note** I have added the `['config']` element to namespace your config away from anything else you may be tempted to place in `$GLOBALS`.

### variable `unset()`

Another possibility is that you might be calling `unset($baseurl)` somewhere else in the code, which would be marking the variable as undefined.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. Using require_once for my settings.php file has solved it. Many thanks for the in depth reply.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Still can't get this working. Using $GLOBALS[] still getting undefined when calling it.

Answer (score 0):

If you define it in `settings.php`, it should be available **in the global scope** of all the included scripts. When you enter a function, the scope changes so the variable won't be available unless you 'import' it by declaring `global $baseurl;` at the start of the function (not advised, though).

Answer (score 0):

If `settings.php` is included first, and `$baseurl` is defined as a global variable in `settings.php`, it will be available in all subsequently included files.  If the variable is defined inside a function in `settings.php`, it will need to be defined as a global there:

```
$GLOBALS['baseurl'] = 'theurl';
```

If it is accessed within a function in any of the subsequently included files, it will need to be accessed via `$GLOBALS[]` there too:

```
echo $GLOBALS['baseurl'];
```

If you are expecting to access a global variable from multiple files, it is highly recommended to *always* use the `$GLOBALS[]` array since it remains clear in any scope that the variable is being set and accessed globally.

Answer (score 0):

If you require() the files in a function, the variables are defined in the scope of the function: They are not global.

Use `$GLOBALS['baseurl'] = '...';` in settings.php